# Set Default ComboBox Value in Listview

Tags: c#, listview, webview, uwp, combobox

I have a webview and a combobox inside a listview whose data is fetched from the server.
I want the default value of combox to match the string below:

```
string A = "A:C:B:D:E";
```

XAML:

```
<ListView
    Name="ListPairOption"
    Height="auto">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:PairClass">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid
                    x:Name="pilganStack"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Margin="10,10,10,10"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Background="#FFDFF6EE">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <WebView
                        x:Name="option"
                        Margin="5,5,5,5"
                        MinHeight="60"
                        Height="auto"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        local:MyProperties.HtmlString="{Binding Name}"
                        DefaultBackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
                    <TextBlock
                        x:Name="index"
                        FontSize="20"
                        Text="{Binding Ind}" 
                        Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                </Grid>
                <ComboBox
                    x:Name="pairOption"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Margin="10,10,10,0"
                    DisplayMemberPath="NameA"
                    SelectedValuePath="Pilgan"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.PilihanS, ElementName=ListPairOption}"
                    Background="#FFDFF6EE"
                    FontSize="17"
                    FontWeight="SemiBold"
                    PlaceholderText="Pilih"
                    Foreground="Black"
                    PlaceholderForeground="Black"
                    CornerRadius="10,10,10,10" 
                    SelectionChanged="pairOption_SelectionChanged" 
                    BorderBrush="#FF79D9BD" 
                    BorderThickness="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Code:

```
private List<MyClass> _items;
string urlPath = "https://";
 var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());
 var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(urlPath);
string jsonText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
double id = jsonObject["EXAM_ASM_A_ID"].GetNumber();
string questionID = jsonObject["EXAM_QUESTION_ID"].GetString();
string choiceA = questionObject.ContainsKey("choice_a") && questionObject["choice_a"] != null ? questionObject["choice_a"].GetString() : string.Empty;
string choiceB = questionObject.ContainsKey("choice_b") && questionObject["choice_b"] != null ? questionObject["choice_b"].GetString() : string.Empty;
string choiceC = questionObject.ContainsKey("choice_c") && questionObject["choice_c"] != null ? questionObject["choice_c"].GetString() : string.Empty;
string choiceD = questionObject.ContainsKey("choice_d") && questionObject["choice_d"] != null ? questionObject["choice_d"].GetString() : string.Empty;
string choiceE = questionObject.ContainsKey("choice_e") && questionObject["choice_e"] != null ? questionObject["choice_e"].GetString() : string.Empty;
_items = new List<MyClass>();
_items.Add(new MyClass() { Name = choiceA });
_items.Add(new MyClass() { Name = choiceB });
_items.Add(new MyClass() { Name = choiceC });
_items.Add(new MyClass() { Name = choiceD });
_items.Add(new MyClass() { Name = choiceE });
 string c = "";
 string v1 = "";
 JsonArray mapArray = questionObject["map"].GetArray();
 foreach (JsonValue mapValue in mapArray)
 {
     JsonArray mapArrayI = mapValue.GetArray();
     PairClass pair = new PairClass();
     foreach (JsonValue mapValueI in mapArrayI)
     {
         string choice = "";
         try
         {
             if (mapValueI.ToString().All(char.IsDigit))
             {
                 c = String.Concat(mapValueI.ToString().Where(Char.IsDigit));
                 index = Int16.Parse(c);
                 pair.Ind = index;
             }
             else
             {
                 string v = mapValueI.ToString();
                 var collection = Regex.Matches(v, "\\\"(.*?)\\\"");
                 foreach (var item in collection)
                 {
                     v1 = item.ToString().Trim('"');
                     choice = v1;
                     pair.Name = choice;
                 }
             }
         }
         catch
         {
         }
     }
     itemL.Add(pair);
 }
 JsonArray pairArray = questionObject["pairs"].GetArray();
 foreach (JsonValue pairValue in pairArray)
 {
     string pairKey = "";
     string pairString = "";
     JsonArray pairArrayI = pairValue.GetArray();
     foreach (JsonValue pairValueI in pairArrayI)
     {
         try
         {
             string v = pairValueI.ToString();
             if (Regex.IsMatch(v, @"\b[A-E]\b"))
             {
                 var collection = Regex.Matches(v, "\\\"(.*?)\\\"");
                 foreach (var item in collection)
                 {
                     string v2 = item.ToString().Trim('"');
                     pairKey = v2;
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 var collection = Regex.Matches(v, "\\\"(.*?)\\\"");
                 foreach (var item in collection)
                 {
                     string v3 = item.ToString().Trim('"');
                     pairString = v3;
                     //Debug.WriteLine("pair string: " + pairString);
                     if(pairString.Contains("&amp;"))
                     {
                         pairString = pairString.Replace("&amp;", " & ");
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         catch
         {
         }
     }
     PilihanS.Add(new ComboBoxClass() { Pilgan = pairKey, NameA = pairString });
 }
 ListPairOption.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
 var list = itemL.OrderBy(p => p.Ind).ToList();
 ListPairOption.ItemsSource = list;

    public class MyClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.Name;
        }
    }
```

PairClass.cs

```
public class PairClass
{
    public int Ind { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ComboBoxClass> PilihanS { get; set; }

    public PairClass()
    {
        Ind = int.MinValue;
        Name = string.Empty;
        PilihanS = new ObservableCollection<ComboBoxClass>();
    }

    public PairClass(int ind, string name, string pilihan)
    {
        Ind = ind;
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class ComboBoxClass
{
    public string Pilgan { get; set; }
    public string NameA { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.NameA;
    }
}
```

How do I set the default value for the combobox in the listview?

Note:

- if from the string above then the listview has 5 indexes
- The first character in the string is the combobox value for the first choice at the first index in the listview
- The 3rd character in the string is the combobox value for the third option at the 2nd index in the listview
- The 5th character in the string is the combobox value for the second option at the 3rd index in the listview
- The 7th character in the string is the combobox value for the fourth option at the 4th index in the listview
- The 9th character in the string is the combobox value for the fifth option at the 5th index in the listview
  For more details, see the image below:
  [image]
  [image: combobox value]

Comment: Create a new property inside the `PairClass` class and bind `SelectedIndex` property of Combobox to it. You can calculator the index value as you want when you get data from server.

Answer (score 0):

> Set Default ComboBox Value

If you want to set default comboBox value, you could try to bind `SelectedIndex`  property to a value of your datacontext. When you set the `SelectedIndex`, combobox will show the value at the index of the source.

In your scenario, the `PairClass` is the datacontext of your `ComboBox`, so you could create a new property in `PairClass` and use it to bind to `SelectedIndex` property of the ComboBox.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure default values have to be set in the constructor of the code-behind file for the ComboBox.

Comment: How to set selectedindex combobox inside listview?

Comment: Setting in the code behind is not the only way. In this scenario, binding is a better solution.

Comment: I have tried `SelectedIndex={"Binding selectedInd, Mode=TwoWay"}` but it still doesn't work

Comment: Don't forget to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in order to actually update the binding when the source value changes.  In this scenario (and given I understand the code structure correctly), I'd create a DependencyProperty (a.k.a. 'propdp') in PairClass of type Int32, and bind the ComboBox to that.  No INotifyPropertyChanged interface needed and greater control over property changed events.